# Displaying the constraints in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, sqlplus

Hello I am trying to display the constraints in one of my tables but for some reason I get the message no rows selected.  Noted below is the table I have created.

```
Create table Teams (
   TeamID varCHAR2(4) constraint Teams_TeamID_PK Primary Key,
   TeamName VARCHAR2(40) 
);
```

This is the code I am using to show my constraints.

```
SELECT constraint_name, 
       constraint_type,
       search_condition
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE table_name = 'Teams';
```

I am a rookie so I want to make sure I understand what is wrong.  I have tried to drop the table thinking that my constraints did not take - I did not, nor did I receive any errors when I created the table and I am referencing TeamID in another table.  So when I try to drop the table I get an error message when is what I was hoping for.

Comment: Your issue strikes me as that you are performing this actions as different users and/or aren't committing the transaction when you create the table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE is DDL that autocommits upon execution in Oracle.

Comment: You can't drop a table that is referenced by other tables, unless you specify "CASCADE CONSTRAINTS", i.e. "DROP TABLE Teams CASCADE CONSTRAINTS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select dbms_mview.get_ddl('TABLE',USER,'TEAMS') from dual;
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
SELECT constraint_name, 
       constraint_type,
       search_condition
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE table_name = 'TEAMS';
```

Unless double-quoted when created, all object names in Oracle are upper case.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code:

```
show create table table_name;
```

Comment: Will work in MySQL but not in MS SQL Server and Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

I personally use:

```
SELECT * FROM all_constraints WHERE Table_Name = <TableName>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the CamelCase names, your create table script should have been:

```
Create table "Teams" ( 
  "TeamID" varCHAR2(4) constraint "Teams_TeamID_PK" Primary Key, 
  "TeamName" VARCHAR2(40)  
);
```

Without double-quotes Oracle helpfully converts all identifiers to uppercase :)

Answer (score 1):

Type the table name in upper case in `where` clause within the single quotes.

e.g. `WHERE table_name = 'TEAMS';`

Comment: The SQL keywords are case insensitive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive