# SQL statement to display table names, its structures, and constraint information

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Im looking for an Oracle SQL statement that will show me all the table names, structures and constraint information that I have created.

Would it be something along the lines of

```
Select * from user_tables;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying the constraints in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837793/displaying-the-constraints-in-a-table) and [Get list of all tables in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle) and [How can I describe a table in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855209/how-can-i-describe-a-table-in-oracle-without-using-the-describe-command)

Comment: All the data dictionary views are documented in the Reference manual which is online.  Read it here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/index.htm#US

Answer (score 0):

This is the official oracle query you should use to select the tables for the current user:

```
  SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
```

or

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM dba_tables
```

or

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM all_tables
```

for selecting all constraints for a table:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ""
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME='EMP';
```

(This will list you all the constraints from that particular user in which you are logged in.)