# Query to select all the table names that doesn't have their name in upper case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone provide me a query to select the list of all tables in a db that doesn't have their names in uppercase?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive

Comment: How are you going to differentiate between "ThisTable", "THISTABLE" and "thistable". Best to assume no case sensitivity in database tables and fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@gbn's answer is correct for any up to date version of SQL Server.

For 2000:

```
SELECT * FROM
sysobjects
WHERE
   UPPER(name) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN <> name COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(ID,N'IsTable')=1 and OBJECTPROPERTY(ID,N'IsMSShipped')=0
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM
sys.tables -- or local equivalent. This is for SQL Server
WHERE
   UPPER(name) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN <> name COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Comment: @Srivastava - have you considered providing a little more detail than "it's not working"? Is it giving you results you know are incorrect, is it giving an error message (that you could tell people trying to help you)?

Comment: yes it is pointing error lile this Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.tables'.

Comment: @Srivastava - OK, so you're using SQL Server 2000 (or earlier), so you'll need to use `sysobjects` instead of `sys.tables`, and add ` AND OBJECTPROPERTY(ID,N'IsTable')=1 and OBJECTPROPERTY(ID,N'IsMSShipped')=0` to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Table names in select statements may be case insensitive, but that doesn't mean you can't return names of tables that are not uppercase:

```
SELECT  name
FROM    sys.tables
WHERE   (name <> UPPER(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name <> UPPER(name) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE CAST(name as varbinary) <> CAST(UPPER(name) as varbinary)
```