# Are Table names in a Query supposed to be Case-SensitIvE?

Tags: mysql, database, language-agnostic

Are Table names in a Query supposed to be Case-SensitIvE in MySQL?

For example, if I do the following:

```
var query = "SELECT something FROM thAt WHERE this = '". $everything ."'";
```

If the actual table name is all lowercase, and I use a combination of upper and lowercase in my select query, SHOULD it match? Is table names in queries *supposed* to be case-(in)sensitive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is SQL syntax case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From < [Is SQL syntax case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive) >:

> Mysql has a configuration option to enable/disable it. Usually case-sensitive table and column names are the default on Linux MySql and case-insensitive used to be the default on Windows, but now the installer asked about this during setup. For MSSQL it is a function of the database's collation setting.
>
> Here is the MySql page about name case-sensitivity: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html
>
> Here is the article in MSDN about collations for MSSQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143503(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), case sensitivity of table names is filesystem-dependent.  On Windows, they are case insensitive.