# How to make SQL case sensitive

Tags: sql, ms-access, case-sensitive

I have an Access database set up on a domain hosting service. I am connecting to it through SQL. However, I need all of my queries to be case sensitive, and as far as I know the way the server is set up on the hosting service is it's NOT case sensitive. Is there a certain command that I could use in my SQL which would make the query case sensitive?

Comment: You may find inspiration in this related, but not duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: @BobKaufman thanks, I have already seen this question before I asked this question.

Comment: @Lamak I believe I am using Microsoft db engine.

Comment: Then you can take the idea from @Niklas 's answer, but you can make your default collation for your entire database case sensitive. `Latin1_General_CS_AS` is an example.

Comment: So how would I make my default collation case sensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can add collate after the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT col FROM table  
WHERE col COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'value'
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that now.  If I have WHERE col COLLATE abc = 'value' AND... I would put the collate after the AND as well, right?

Comment: When I am using UPDATE, I would not need the COLLATE, correct?

Comment: That depends. If you want to update where *'value' = 'value'* but not where *'value' = 'VALUE'* then you do need to use collate.

Comment: I just tried it, and I am getting a syntax error. I am missing an operator somewhere.  Here is my SQL statement: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE username='username' AND password COLLATE password='password'`

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I made a mistake :) Now, I have `SELECT * FROM table WHERE username COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'username' AND password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'password'`. I am still getting a syntax error (missing operator).

Comment: @Niklas I already accepted it before, I must have accidentally unaccepted it. Sorry.

Comment: What happens if you place collate at the end instead? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = 'username' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`

Comment: Same problem. Is there any way to change the collation for the whole database for all new records in the DB? I don't necessarily need to put the COLLATE for every query if the whole database is already set on a certain collation, right?

Comment: Oh, I thought you didn't have access to the DB?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN username varchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Niklas I have access to the DB, but I don't have access to the server it is running on

Comment: @Niklas when I try your idea, I get a syntax error on the `ALTER TABLE` statement. Is there anything I need to do to the DB before running this code? Right now, that is the first query that is run.
Also, remember I am using the Microsoft ODBC driver, if that makes any difference.

Comment: It is apparent from the chain of comments that this answer never worked, despite @futurevilla216 marking it as the accepted answer.  To be clear for future readers, **This answer is not correct for MS Access (Jet/ACE) databases.  COLLATE is not a valid SQL keyword for MS Access queries.**

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to set the entire DB to case sensitive, or is it just part of some queries. If it is a query term then you can use these to force case sensitive matching:

```
StrComp("A","a",0)
```

The 0 in the method signature is to perform a binary comparison giving you the case sensitivity you want. It returns an integer.

```
WHERE StrComp('myText1', 'MYTeXt1', 0) = 0
```

[Documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/strcomp-function-HA001228914.aspx)

Comment: I need my entire DB to be case sensitive.

Comment: When I tried `WHERE ASC(text1) = ASC(text2)` I get an invalid procedure call. For the first one you suggested, how would that work? Would I just type `WHERE StrComp('myText1','MYTeXt1')`?

Comment: I just tried it, and I am getting the same thing as the ASC. How would you use StrComp if I am comparing it to a whole field? Technically, it's not a string.