# Accent-insensitive query in MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Looking for an MS Access 2013 query that would treat Gutiérrez and Gutierrez as being equivalent strings.

Comment: You're looking for `Option Compare`? See [Documentation.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3992/vba-option-keyword/13937/option-compare-binary-text-database#t=201703042022356956831).

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Sorry, but I don't see how Option Compare helps me (solves my problem).  Or are you saying accent-insensitive string comparison is not possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5747698/1188513 - set the database's *collation*, or use `StrComp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query uses a [LIKE clause](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Like-Operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931?CorrelationId=008164b0-268f-477c-8f54-ded00399e577&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA001231490) with a character range to match both names:

```sql
SELECT ID, LastName
FROM Table1
WHERE LastName LIKE 'Guti[e,é]rrez';
```

Unfortunately, the Access Database Engine does not support accent-insensitive collation like SQL Server does, so tweaking the "database sort order" of the Access database won't help.