# How to make a SELECT in PHP/MySQL case insensitive?

Tags: php, mysql

Her's my probleme, i guess its really basic.

I'm trying to lookup in the database if a line does exist. heres my code :

```
$req="SELECT * FROM INSTITUTS WHERE inst_name='$fc_inst'";
$result=mysql_query($req) or die ('Erreur :'.mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
echo '  name exist';
}
else {
echo '  does not exist.';
}
```

Probleme is, when imm looking for "test", it says does not exist, even if i have "Test" in my database.

Comment: MySQL's queries are case insensitive by default, unless the underlying tables have a case-sensitive collation set.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use `LIKE`:

```
WHERE foo LIKE 'bar'
```

Or you can cast both lowercase with:

```
WHERE LOWER(foo) = LOWER("bar")
```

The example with `LOWER()` is most effective where you know that all of your data in the database is already lower cased and then you can just execute:

```
WHERE foo = LOWER("bar")
```

This would be a cheaper comparison than the `LIKE` if you can lower case all of the data in your database.

Comment: i am sure in some areas, some info **has to** be uppercase or mixed case and cannot be all lowercase

Answer (score 11):

Try using `LIKE` instead of `=`:

```
$req="SELECT * FROM INSTITUTS WHERE `inst_name` LIKE '$fc_inst'";
```

Comment: This will work ?, he should not use Lower() in statement and strtolower() in PHP code ?

Comment: @Vash, is that a question or statement?

Comment: MySQL is generally case insensitive within LIKE queries unless you go out of your way to make it not the case.

Comment: @Vash: It's not how MySQL engine works, it's an **SQL** thing. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

It could also be a problem with your table COLLATE setting

This CREATE statement will force your select queries to be case sensitive even when using LIKE operators:

```
CREATE
  table instituts (inst_name VARCHAR(64))
  CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs;
```

Whereas this one will ensure case-insensitivity:

```
CREATE
  table instituts (inst_name VARCHAR(64))
  CHARACTER SET latin1
```

Comment: This is possibly the most sensible answer.

Answer (score 4):

you can solve it using "LIKE" as other people told you, **BUT** it is important to know that the case sensitivity is determined by the collation in the database. For example if you select a collation utf8_general_ci... that "ci" at the end means "case insensitive" so the comparisons you do in the future will be case insensitive.

**In a few words: you have to be careful about the collation you select.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use a MD5() comparison if you want a **case sensitive** select:

```
$req="SELECT * FROM INSTITUTS WHERE MD5(inst_name)=MD5('$fc_inst')";
```

of course you consume a little bit of the server's cpu but it's rather simpler than those boring collations.

Comment: *"a little bit of the server's cpu"* can mean a few hours of CPU if the table is big and the query is frequently run.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$req="SELECT * FROM INSTITUTS WHERE UCASE(inst_name)=UCASE('$fc_inst')";
$result=mysql_query($req) or die ('Erreur :'.mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
echo '  name exist';
}
else {
echo '  does not exist.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE BINARY in your query..

Like this:

> SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` LIKE BINARY 'search_string'

this will check "search_string" data in case sensitive