# php query(lowercase/uppercase letters) validate

Tags: mysql, sql, collation

I need select result from mysql regarding query string.
Let's string will be:
**Z** and **z** (uppercase and lowercase)

How database look like:

```
url_id      test_char
1           Z
2           z
```

Ok, in address bar entered: localhost/z
This query always selecting 1 result, first one, so it returns always 1. If i try even z.

The test_char is varchar.

How to make Z and z select diferrent results ?

Comment: What's the collation? It can be set at the table, or database levee...  If the collation is _ci, that means "Case Insensitive"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses [case insensitive searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) by default for non binary strings or certain collation types.

Per **OMG Ponies** note, you could adjust this at the DB or Table level. Alternatively, you could adjust it inline for your specific query. Examples of each are in the docs linked above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP go to localhost/phpmyadmin/ and access your database and change it to Case Sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is best use function MD5 (PHP and SQl are work)

Look a example:
[How to make a SELECT in PHP/MySQL case insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938037/how-to-make-a-select-in-php-mysql-case-insensitive#answer-6956394)

Sorry bad english!