# Case sensitive password query but not username

Tags: php, mysql

What's the easiest way to re-phrase this query so that the username is *not* case-sensitive but the password *is* case-sensitive?

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: please refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938037/how-to-make-a-select-in-php-mysql-case-insensitive

Comment: Unrelated to your question, please don't directly use PHP variables in your queries, as it makes you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Further to the above comment, don't use `mysql` functions, as they are being deprecated. Switch to `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: As another aside, please consider using `mysqli_` instead of `mysq_l` as `mysql_` is now deprecated.

Comment: Storing passwords in plain text is bad practice. Please see this ancient (2007) blog post from Jeff Atwood. [http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/)

Comment: **DON'T** store the password as plain text and **don't** write your own "encryption" routine. Use well-established encryption (or hashing) code for passwords.

Comment: [**B.5.5.1 Case Sensitivity in String Searches** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to let the database handle the case sensitivity. In order to do that you have to change the collation 
of the field `username` or `password` (it depends of their current collation).

All you have to do is to change the collation of the field `username` to a collation whose name ends with `_ci` (it stands for `case insensitive`) and the collation of the field `password` to a collation whose name ends with `_cs` (from `case sensitive`).

The actual names of the collations depend on the character set of your table.

For example, this is the definition of a table that uses `latin1` as a charset:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If you change the collation you don't need to worry about the case sensitivity of the values any more and you don't need to change the queries.

#### Sample code using the table above

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`)
    -> VALUES ('John Doe', 'passwd1'), ('john doe', 'PASSWD1');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'JOHN DOE';
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | John Doe | passwd1  |
|  2 | john doe | PASSWD1  |
+----+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password` = 'passwd1';
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | John Doe | passwd1  |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Alternative solution, using the excellent suggestion of @spencer7593

You don't need to change the collation of the fields (it is recommended but if you cannot do it then this is an alternative solution). You can force the collation you want in the query:

Force case sensitive comparison of `username`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` COLLATE latin1_general_cs = 'john doe';
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
|  2 | john doe | PASSWD1  |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Force case insensitive comparison of `password`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password` COLLATE latin1_general_ci = 'passwd1';
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | John Doe | passwd1  |
|  2 | john doe | PASSWD1  |
+----+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Or, if OP can't (or doesn't want to) change the collation of the column(s), OP can also specify collation (using the **`COLLATE`** keyword) in the SELECT statement. +1 [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collate.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collate.html) Available collation names can be retrieved with `SHOW COLLATION` statement.

Comment: @spencer7593 excellent idea! I learned something today too. Thank you.

Comment: good answer to the general problem, but encourages a terribly bad habit of storing a plaintext password :/

Answer (score 1):

Just normalise the case.

```
$query = mysql_query(
    "
        SELECT *
        FROM login
        WHERE
            password='$password'
            AND LOWER(username)=LOWER('$username')
    ",
    $connection
) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This way you cannot use an index on `username`.

Comment: True, best to user `LOWER` when inserting users into the DB and then you can use just the second `LOWER` for the comparison.

Comment: I thought that queries are case-insensitive? This would only work if you could force the query to be case-sensitive.

Comment: @AndyGroom see axiac's answer above. My answer only applies if you're case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Quite Simply you can use a `LIKE`, for example:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username LIKE '$username'", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Alternatively you can do partial matches like so, but this is not what you need:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username LIKE '%$username%'", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```