# EntitySpaces dynamic query for Oracle in Multi Provider Mode is not recognizing field

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, entityspaces

Previously, i was using Oracle for my app and all dynamic queries were working fine. Now i have shifted to Multiprovider mode and using SQL Server too.

I generated entities as `Template -> EntitySpaces -> 2009 -> C# -> Generated - Classes Master (C#) -> Execute`. I generated Metadata classes as `Template -> EntitySpaces -> 2009 -> C# -> MultiProvider -> MetadataMap(C#) -> Execute` for both.

While generating, Ignore Schema and Catalog options were unchecked and Target Multiple Data Providers was checked.

Dynamic queries for SQL Server are running fine but for Oracle it is not. On Oracle, i get following error

```
ORA-00904: "Field_Name": invalid identifier
```

Even `LoadByPrimaryKey` is giving the same error.
The `LastQuery` property shows that all fields are written as `"FIELD_NAME"`. It looks `"` is causing the problem. The query works fine if `"` is removed.

How can i remove `"` from dynamic queries? Is there any configuration parameter to guide EntitySpaces not to add `"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle 10g v 10.2 and higher are case sensitive when field names are enclosed in double quotes, there are case sensitive collations for SQL Server and other databases support case sensitivity as well

[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm)

[SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726#Terms)

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive)