# Case Sensitive in Mysql using select where Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select

Hi I am using Java front end and Mysql Backend,,,

Actually in **tbl_test** contains

```
name value
---------------
 abc   22   
 xyz   14   
 ABC   32   
 xyZ    4   
 ABc    4
```

In java I try to retrieve **abc's value** so written a code

```
ResultSet result=stmt.executeQuery("select value from tbl_test where name='abc'");
while(result.next())
{
     System.out.println("Answer : "+result.getInt(1));
}
result.close();
```

The current output is

```
Answer :  22
Answer :  32
Answer :  4
```

Actually i want the result only 'abc' ie **Answer : 22**

I found result also, with below code

```
String name="abc";
ResultSet result=stmt.executeQuery("select name, value from tbl_test where name='"+name+"'");
while(result.next())
  {
    if(name.equals(result.getString(1))
       System.out.println("Answer : "+result.getInt(2));
  }
result.close();
```

Now i getting correct output, but this result from java code not in query,,, Is it possible to retrieve the same result in query...

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the MySQL [`Binary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) operator:

```
select value 
from tbl_test 
where CAST(name AS BINARY) ='abc';
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d507/1).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use case sensitive search for example, or use Binary serach like Mahmoud said

```
select value from tbl_test where name  COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE 'abc'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html