# Uppercase and Lowercase in MySQL query condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a SQL query which uses WHERE statement to find the record. The problem is MySQL seems not care about uppercase and lowercase string in the condition. My both bellow queries have same result.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = 'http://domain.com/aaa'`

=> `http://domain.com/aaa` record (CORRECT)

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = 'http://domain.com/AAA'`

=> `http://domain.com/aaa` record (INCORRECT)

I searched on the Internet and tried to use `BINARY` and `COLLATE utf8_bin` but it didn't help. How can I make it work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the collate of that table?

Comment: Hi @frlan, it is `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: This http://alvinalexander.com/sql/sql-select-case-insensitive-query-queries-upper-lower may help shed some light on the subject. Also `Select Title from FooName where binary Title like '%foo%'` from http://technikhil.wordpress.com/2007/09/17/case-sensitive-matches-in-mysql/

Comment: or `WHERE BINARY url = '....'` if you can't/won't change the collation.

Comment: utf8_general_ci...the ci means case insensitive...so change the collation to one that is case sensitive.

Comment: you tried `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = 'http://domain.com/AAA' COLLATE utf8_bin` correct?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive

Comment: @Rudolfwm I tried both `BINARY` and `COLLATE utf8_bin` but it does not work when I use the phpmyadmin querybox. Then I used the mysql command-line, and it work correctly. It is quite strange and I don't know why.

Comment: @Ngo Duy Khanh : from what I remember, phpmyadmin adds collation automatically so that may override your query. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql query is not case sensitive by default but you can try binary operator to make it case sensitive. Here is the code which should work for you

**For URL `http://domain.com/aaa`**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY url = http://domain.com/aaa
```

**For URL `http://domain.com/AAA`**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY url = http://domain.com/AAA
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

ok, you wants to have case sensitive comparison than you `BINARY` is the only best choice

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE BINARY url = 'http://domain.com/aaa'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL's built-in string functions

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url = LOWER('http://domain.com/AAA')
```

REF: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html