# session.createCriteria(type) is querying table name in lowercase

Tags: mysql, hibernate, session

Hibernate session is generating query with table name in Lowercase for example:

type = Employee.class but table is EMPLOYEE

but query is *** from Emloyee where ***

And because of this SQL exception of table doesnt exist!!

result = session.createCriteria(type).add(Restrictions.eq("Id", Id)).list();

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: And have you told Hibernate what the table name was? How comes the name is case-sensitive? Why do that?

Comment: Yes I have done this  .......                                          final Class type = abc.xyz.Employee.class;

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions. How can Hibernate know that the table name is EMPLOYEE? Why is the name case-sensitive?

Comment: via my POJO isnt it? I am new to hibernate. Can you make me understand what is needed to tell hibernate.

Comment: And the code of the POJO is? Is there anything in that code that tells Hibernate "hey, my class is Employee, but the corresponding table name is EMPLOYEE, not Employee"?

Comment: Actually in my pojo @Table(name="COMPONENT" is not written that is why I am confused too. But when I insert data it does insert correctly. the problem is when I am trying to read. and Pojo is not created by me its legacy code.

Comment: This is extremely confusing. Post the code of the entity, the code you're executing, and the complete stack trace of the exception you get.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL is case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive) so these two selects are equivalent:

```
select * from Emloyee where id = 1
SELECT * FROM EMLOYEE WHERE ID = 1
```

Make sure Hibernate doesn't attempt to select against the PUBLIC schema while your tables are located in a different schema Hibernate is not aware of.