# "SQLite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name" Are column names not case sensitive?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite.net

I am using SQLLite.Net-PCL 3.1.1 in one of my projects and I ran in to the **"SQLite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name"** issue when creating the table in SQLite.

The reason was because my parent class (which I don't own) has a column named **"ID"**. My interface has a column named **"Id"**, note the casing.

I solved this issue by adding the following line of code to my derived class:

```
[Ignore]
public new long ID { get; set; }
```

Where the [Ignore] attribute prevents the "ID" column from being added to my SQLite db which solves my issue.

My question is: are column names in SQLite **not** case sensitive by design or is this a bug?

Comment: I think column named are case insensitive, but even if they were case sensitive using the same name would be inviting trouble later on IMO.

Comment: They're case-insensitive unless you're referencing them in quotations.  So `select id from table` and `select "ID" from table` are not the same.  Probably relevant here.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19933159/2193107

Comment: This is how the SQL language is defined.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, all SQL identifers [are case-insensitive](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_naming.html) (even when quoted).