# SQL Stored Procedure Deleting all rows in table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to delete a single row using a stored procedure in MySQL, however the stored procedure is deleting all rows. The stored procedure is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sherattd`@`%` PROCEDURE `deleteFilm`(in ID int)
BEGIN
    delete from films where id=ID;
END
```

The table I am trying to delete from has headings:

```
create table films (
   id int(8),
   title varchar(100),
   year int(8),
   director varchar(100),
   stars varchar(100),
   review text);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is SQL syntax case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you use as parameter the same name as the column name. It is case insensitive.

```
where id=id
```

is always true. Choose another parameter name!

Answer (score 0):

Parameter name needs to be different as per answer by @juergen d

e.g.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`sherattd`@`%` PROCEDURE `deleteFilm`(in FID int)
BEGIN
    delete from films where id=FID;
END
```