# How to make column names case-sensitive of Sqlite3 in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to create a table as below:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
con = sql.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursour()
sql_command = "create table test(dose float, Dose float, DOSE float)"
cur.execute(sql_command)
```

But i got an error: OperationalError: duplicate column name: Dose.
I wonder how to make the table title case-sensitive?

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite column names are case-insensitive, according to [this](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Is-sqlite-case-sensitive-td75706.html). I think it is enforced on C level of implementation.

As a side-note, mixing column names `dose`, `Dose`, etc does not seem a great idea even if permitted, unless as an exploratory exercise.

Also this can be useful: [Is SQL syntax case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive)