# Can postgresql be configured to treat all identifiers as case sensitive?

Tags: postgresql

- I'm writing java
- I want the db to be case sensitive for table and column names
- I don't want to quote identifiers in my sql because it'll look like this in java:

```java
String sql = "SELECT * FROM \"Seat\"";
```

Is it possible to configure postgres to **always** treat identifiers as case sensitive, **even without** quotes?

Comment: No, that's not possible and it would violate the identifier rules of the SQL standard. It's like asking "*Can I configure my Java compiler to treat all identifiers as case-insensitive*" - it would also violate the rules of the language

Comment: Related: [Is SQL syntax case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153944/190597)

Comment: All that said, if you never quote your identifiers, and you don't choose colliding names (e.g. "Seat" and "seat"), you won't run into a problem. Everything collapses to lowercase unless quoted, so the problem is straightforward to avoid.

Comment: @jmelesky that was my initial plan, but then a column named end needed to be quoted because it's a keyword. I got the ORM to quote everything all the time so that I don't have to configure which names are keywords, but that's how I found out that quotes also affect case sensitivity.