# Java PreparedStatement preserve table name casing

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, wildfly, h2

I have this Java snippet, running inside a WildFly server backed by MariaDB:

```java
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM vehicles;");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

which gives me the following exception:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "VEHICLES" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM vehicles; [42102-193]
```

So, apparentally, it decided to uppercase the table name, which I don't want. How can I turn it off?

Comment: Are you sure that this is not just logging it as upper case?

Comment: Have you tried putting the table name [in quotes](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#quoted_name)? So, in Java that would be `"SELECT * FROM \"vehicles\";"`. Also, you tag mariadb, but the error is h2 - is that relevant?

Comment: SQL is not case-sensitive. There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: @user207421 - is that not implementation-specific? Keywords, I agree - it does not matter. But for [object names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153944/is-sql-syntax-case-sensitive) - doesn't that depend on the RDBMS and maybe also how it is configured?

Comment: @andrewjames True. What I'm really wondering is why the OP objects to an error message that only developers should ever see.

Comment: @andrewjames You're right about H2, I never noticed that... Weird, I'll have to look into that. As for the others, see my comment on Mark's answer. MariaDB on *nix IS case-sensitive for object names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, SQL dialects are - usually - case insensitive by default, but store the table name in uppercase (some dialects will store in lowercase). This means that if you use `select * from vehicle`, you're actually selecting from a table called `VEHICLE`, and error messages will reflect that name, because the table `vehicle` is a different entity than the table `VEHICLE`.

If you want to have the original case reflected in the error message, you need to select from a table really called `vehicle`. To do that you will need to quote the object name in all your SQL statements, eg `select * from "vehicle"`, or - in MariaDB and MySQL - `` select * from `vehicle` ``. Quoted object names retain their original case.

Comment: While this may be true for some DBMSes (like Oracle), I run a MariaDB instance on Linux, where keywords are case insensitive but object names - tables, databases, views etc. - are not. I defined them as lowercase, so they must be accessed as lowercase. I'll try the quoting though.

```
MariaDB [dbname]> select * from vehicles;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [dbname]> select * from Vehicles;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'dbname.Vehicles' doesn't exist
```

Comment: @BenceCsókás The error in your question is from H2, not from MySQL or MariaDB.