# C# SqlDataReader Get Value By Column Name (Case Insensitive)

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, datareader

Using the methods of the `SqlDataReader`, I can get the value of a column by passing in its name.

```
while (dr.Read())
{  
    size = dr["size"].ToString();
    name = dr["name"].ToString();
}
```

In my case, the SQL script is created dynamically and column names can be typed in lower or upper cases. When I try to get value like

`size = dr["size"].ToString();`

it returns `size`, but

`size = dr["Size"].ToString();`

throws an exception. How to get column value by column name case insensitive, is it possible without changing SQL script?

Comment: What are you using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` or `System.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? / Look at [1](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-case-sensitive/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153944/5045688)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating mapping from case-insensitive column name to column ordinal. Something like (not tested):

```cs
var mapper = reader.GetColumnSchema()
    .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => c.ColumnOrdinal.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    
while (dr.Read())
{   
    size = dr[mapper["size"]].ToString();
    name = dr[mapper["name"]].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the column names are case-sensitive when accessing them using the `SqlDataReader` indexer (`dr["columnName"]`). However, you can make the column name comparison case-insensitive by using a `StringComparer` with the `IgnoreCase` option. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve a case-insensitive column name lookup:

```
while (dr.Read())
{  
    size = GetValueIgnoreCase(dr, "size");
    name = GetValueIgnoreCase(dr, "name");
}

// Helper method to retrieve column value case-insensitively
private static string GetValueIgnoreCase(SqlDataReader reader, string columnName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (string.Equals(reader.GetName(i), columnName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
        }
    }

    return null; // Column not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column names into a dictionary first, then look up by column ordinal.

Note that you should ideally cast the values to their real types, rather than using `ToString`.

```cs
var columns = dr.GetColumnSchema().ToDictionary(
  d => d.ColumnName,
  d => d.ColumnOrdinal,
  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
while (dr.Read())
{  
    size = (int)dr[columns["size"]];
    name = (string)dr[columns["name"]];
}
```