# Why does this sql function not work with REPLACE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

I am having a problem with my sql function. The following function operates as expect but when I substitute, it only returns one row:

```
CAST(t.ColumnName as nvarchar(100))
```

for:

```
REPLACE(CAST(t.ColumnName as nvarchar(100)), 'ID', 'Id')
```

What is wrong? Here is my calling code:

```
PRINT dbo.CreatePocoFromTable('dbo.OnePoundFish')
```

Here is the function itself:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CreatePocoFromTable]
    (@SchemaAndName nvarchar(200))
RETURNS Nvarchar(MAX) AS
BEGIN
/* Example call:

PRINT dbo.CreatePocoFromTable('dbo.OnePoundFish')

*/

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100) = SUBSTRING(@SchemaAndName , CHARINDEX('.', @SchemaAndName ) + 1, LEN(@SchemaAndName ))   
DECLARE @TableSchema NVARCHAR(100) = SUBSTRING(@SchemaAndName , 1, CHARINDEX('.', @SchemaAndName ) - 1)  
DECLARE @result Nvarchar(max) = ''

SET @result = @result + 'using System;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) 

IF (@TableSchema IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    SET @result = @result + 'namespace ' + @TableSchema  + CHAR(13) + '{' + CHAR(13) 
END

SET @result = @result + 'public class ' + @TableName + CHAR(13) + '{' + CHAR(13) 

SET @result = @result + '#region Instance Properties' + CHAR(13)  

SELECT @result = @result + CHAR(13) 
    -- BL/DAL/DataRepository Entity attributes
    + '[DataField("' + t.ColumnName + '")]' + CHAR(13)
    + ' public ' + t.ColumnType + ' ' + CAST(t.ColumnName as nvarchar(100)) + ' { get; set; } ' + CHAR(13) 

FROM
(
    SELECT  
        c.COLUMN_NAME   AS ColumnName 
        , CASE c.DATA_TYPE   
            WHEN 'bigint' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int64?' ELSE 'Int64' END
            WHEN 'binary' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'bit' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Boolean?' ELSE 'Boolean' END            
            WHEN 'char' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'date' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetime' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetime2' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetimeoffset' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTimeOffset?' ELSE 'DateTimeOffset' END                                    
            WHEN 'decimal' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                    
            WHEN 'float' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Single?' ELSE 'Single' END                                    
            WHEN 'image' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'int' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int32?' ELSE 'Int32' END
            WHEN 'money' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                
            WHEN 'nchar' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'ntext' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'numeric' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                            
            WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'real' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Double?' ELSE 'Double' END                                                                        
            WHEN 'smalldatetime' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                                    
            WHEN 'smallint' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int16?' ELSE 'Int16'END            
            WHEN 'smallmoney' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                                        
            WHEN 'text' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'time' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'TimeSpan?' ELSE 'TimeSpan' END                                                                   

            WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                                    
            WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Byte?' ELSE 'Byte' END                                                
            WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN 'Guid'
            WHEN 'varbinary' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'String'
            ELSE 'Object'
        END AS ColumnType
        , c.ORDINAL_POSITION 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE   c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ISNULL(@TableSchema, c.TABLE_SCHEMA) = c.TABLE_SCHEMA  
) t
ORDER BY t.ORDINAL_POSITION

SET @result = @result + CHAR(13) + '#endregion Instance Properties' + CHAR(13)  

SET @result = @result  + '}' + CHAR(13)

IF (@TableSchema IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    SET @result = @result + CHAR(13) + '}' 
END

  RETURN @Result
END
```

Thanks :)

Comment: How is `REPLACE`, either working or not, related to your function?

Comment: Because the desire outcome is like this: [DataField("ColumnID")]
 public Int32 ColumnId { get; set; } -- where the one format ends with upper case ID and the other proper case -- also it was the REPLACE keyword that prevented it from enumerating more than one row -- So, it's pretty MAJOR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only the interesting part ...

```
SELECT @result = @result + CHAR(13) 
    -- BL/DAL/DataRepository Entity attributes
    + '[DataField("' + CAST(REPLACE(t.ColumnName , 'ID', 'Id') as nvarchar(100))   + '")]' + CHAR(13)
--    + '[DataField("' + t.ColumnName  + '")]' + CHAR(13)

    + ' public ' + t.ColumnType + ' ' + CAST(t.ColumnName as nvarchar(100)) + ' { get; set; } ' + CHAR(13) 

FROM
```

Comment: Bizarre - that's the only variation I didn't try. I'm tired but I was thinking that it wouldn't matter whether I did the replace before the cast or the other way about.

Comment: `CAST ... AS VARCHAR` should be `CAST AS VARCHAR(some length)`. See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: I knew what he meant - The resulting function casts as NVARCHAR(100) - just like the original snippet

Answer (score 0):

Is your sql server set to be case sensitive? If not (and I believe it's not by default) then replace based on different case of the same word will not work.

See this link to change the collation to a case sensitive one [How do I change SQL Server 2005 to be case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137452/how-do-i-change-sql-server-2005-to-be-case-sensitive)

Comment: I am unwilling to change the collation on the whole database. At what level do apply the collation. For example, the following runs but does not give the desired result: PRINT dbo.CreatePocoFromTable('dbo.OnePoundFish') COLLATE Latin1_GENERAL_CS_AS